# Why realloc() in C changes memory?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I thought that `realloc()` function reallocates the memory and doesn't change it.
After debugging an assignment that I had to do I realized that realloc() changed some elements in the memory and created bugs.

So I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *a, *p;
    a = (int*)calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    p = realloc(a, 20);
    p[10] = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

and I got the following output

[image]

Could anybody explain why would this happen?

I tried using `malloc()` instead of `calloc()` but the existing array would also change.

Comment: The new size specified to `realloc()` is in bytes.   If you want new storage for 20 `int`, you need to do `p = realloc(a, 20*sizeof(int))`.   If `sizeof(int)` is 4, `realloc(a, 20)` resizes to an arrayc of five `int`, and accessing elements `5` to `20`as you are gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should also check that the `calloc()` and `realloc()` calls succeed.    They return `NULL` if they fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you've re-allocated *fewer* items than originally allocated with `calloc`. The confusion is due to a slight difference in signatures of `calloc` and `malloc`/`realloc`. The call

```
a = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

allocates 10 blocks of `sizeof(int)`, or 40 bytes on systems with `sizeof(int)` equal to 4, while

```
p = realloc(a, 20);
```

asks to reduce the size of that block to 20 bytes. In other words, `calloc` does multiplication by `sizeof` for you, while `realloc` and `malloc` require you to do multiplication yourself.

Once you told `realloc` that you want only 20 bytes, any access past the end of the fifth integer is undefined behavior.

If you want to extend the size to 20 `int`s, multiply by `sizeof(int)`:

```
p = realloc(a, 20*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri It does not "work", it's undefined behavior that gives an appearance of "working".

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

> The reallocation is done by either:
>
> a) expanding or contracting the existing area pointed to by ptr, if
>   possible. The contents of the area remain unchanged up to the lesser
>   of the new and old sizes. If the area is expanded, the contents of the
>   new part of the array are undefined.
>
> b) allocating a new memory block of size new_size bytes, copying
>   memory area with size equal the lesser of the new and the old sizes,
>   and freeing the old block.

It depends on the implementation of the compiler and the size you're reallocating. If the newly allocated size is not occupi-able without fragment, then the realloc will definitely going to allocate memory in different location, which is more efficient than freeing already used up memory.

Answer (score 0):

`p = realloc(a, 20);`

In this statement, you are reallocating the p to 20/4 = 5.

Accessing undefined memory leads to `undefined behavior`. This means that compiler can behave any way: program crash, garbage value, sometimes correct results.

That's why you are getting garbage values after 5th element.

Edit it to: `p = realloc(a, 20*sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 0):

the statement `a = (int*)calloc(10, sizeof(int));` allocates `10x4` i.e `40` bytes. lets say from `0x100` to `0x140` location.

```
    -----------------------------------------
   |     |    |    |   |    |    |      |    |
    -----------------------------------------
   0x100     ..      0x120                0x140
   a
```

next when you do `realloc()` on same `a` like   `p = realloc(a, 20);` it won't add `20` bytes, it reduces whole memory to `20` bytes itself i.e from `0x100` to `0x120` and now when you access `p[10] = 10;` its out of bound i.e you are trying to put data in around `0x140` location which result in undefined behavior.

```
    --------------------
   |     |      |      | 
    --------------------
   0x100     ..      0x120 
   a                   
   p
```

from the `man 3 realloc`

> The  realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed
>   to
>          by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range from
>          the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes.  If
>          the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not  be
>          initialized.

If you really want to expand existing memory by `20` bytes then do like

```
p = realloc(a ,20*sizeof(int));
```